# Request stops working once I set up httpOptions

Tags: angular, asp.net-apicontroller

So I'm new at angular and I'm trying to make a post request, thing is, I need to set content-type to application/json and once I do that my request stops working, if I send all the variables on the url it works but I'd like to send the pw on the body and for that I need to set the content-type.
For short, if I do this it works:

```
let resp: any;
var req = {
  pw: this.pw
};
this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'login?login=' + this.log + '&key=' + this.key + '&pw=' + this.pw,req)
```

but if I do this it doesn't work (making the changes on the API as well)

```
    const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json; charset=utf-8'
  })
};
let resp: any;
var req = {
  pw: this.pw
};
this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'login?login=' + this.log + '&key=' + this.key,req, httpOptions)
```

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: directly put this `this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'login?login=' + this.log + '&key=' + this.key,req, { headers: new HttpHeaders ({'content-type':'application/json'})})`

Comment: the error on the console is "unkown error"

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error from the console in the question?

Comment: @DavidFaísca what happens if you give something like this                                               
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'content-Type':  'application/json;'
  })

Answer (score 0):

While providing headers to `HttpClient.post()` you have to provide it as a key value pair where the key is `headers`.

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
```

In your post method,

```
this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'login?login=' + this.log + '&key=' + this.key, req, { headers: headers });
```

You can also set the headers in this way,

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Another way to set the headers is to append,

```
let headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

For more details please read the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#http-headers).